# How to employ people from another country where they live abroad?

Tags: employment

I'm setting up a tech startup but I want to employ people from anywhere in the world.

My base would be the UK, but as my startup requires web engineers which are a rare commodity on today's market, specially due to covid, I don't want to be restricted

In the ideal world, I would be able to advertise a job posting for web-developers to be able to work fully remotely. For example, I would happy taking onboard a developer from Australia, Brazil and the UK. Due to general confidentiality agreements, all 3 hypothetical employees would have to be under a full time contract with the startup..

What are the implications of such a setup?

How and where for example would my company in the UK pay employee contributions for example?

Comment: The tax/NIC related implications include whether they are actually employees or self-employed subcontractors for UK tax purposes, and how their own national tax regimes regard such earnings from abroad. Then there's things like insurance, workers' rights and H&S to consider. You should think about seeing an accountant that specialises in non-resident / non-domicile efficiency planning. And HMRC of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can do this

However, your employees would be employed in and subject to the employment law of the jurisdiction where they are located.

So, English employees would be subject to English/Welsh employment law, English/Welsh work health and safely law, English/Welsh superannuation/pension law, you would withhold tax and remit it to the UK Inland Revenue Service, etc. Australian employees would be subject to Australian employment law, Australian work health and safely law, Australian superannuation/pension law, you would withhold tax and remit it to the Australian Tax Office, etc. And so on.